# Get the images from the array object index that corresponds with the album name of what the user clicked

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'll try to explain this as thorough as possible. What I need to do is use `ng-repeat` on an array of images inside of an object, which also sits inside an array. The number of objects in the main array are the number of albums that contains images that the user has created.

So, when a user clicks on the `h1`:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="album in albumsList"> <!-- albumsList in the main array -->
        <a href="#/Albums/view-album">
            <h1 ng-bind="album.albumName"></h1> <!-- takes you to the view-album view -->
        </a>
        <img src="{{album.images.imageList[0]}}"> <!-- thumbnail -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

It routes to the `view-album` view where all the images of that album should be displayed.

Here I've hardcoded the **"winter"** album so that the `ng-repeat` displays all the images of that album:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="image in albumsList[1].images.imageList">
        <img src="{{image}}">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Obviously this isn't what I want. I need to somehow match what the user clicked with the correct object's `albumName` in the main array. How would I do this?

The array containing the information has this structure:

[image: structure of array]

The `imageList` contains all the images.

My routing:

```
flickrApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/feed.php',
            controller: 'flickrCtrl'
        }).
        when('/Albums', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/albums.php',
            controller: 'albumsCtrl'
        }).
        when('/Albums/view-album', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/view-album.php',
            controller: 'albumsCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
}]);
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Shouldn't the url be /Albums/{albumName} to view the album. So your href would be something like `ng-href="#/Albums/{{album.albumName}}"`. Can you please post your basic routing?

Comment: @WayneEllery You're probably right. Will include routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you routing you would change the view album route to `/Albums/:albumName` and it's best to use a separate controller:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/feed.php',
            controller: 'flickrCtrl'
        }).
        when('/Albums', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/albums.php',
            controller: 'albumsCtrl'
        }).
        when('/Albums/:albumName', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/view-album.php',
            controller: 'viewAlbumsCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        });
}]);
```

Then in your view you can pass the album name like so:

```
<a ng-href="#/Albums/{{album.albumName}}">
    <h1 ng-bind="album.albumName"></h1> <!-- takes you to the view-album view -->
</a>
```

Then to get the album name from the url use `$routeParams.albumName`. This can then be used to look up the album by the name:

```
.controller('viewAlbumsCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.albumName = $routeParams.albumName;
})
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IHi9X2loap4MbVQgQ3Ig?p=preview)

Comment: Got that working, but how would I write the hardcoded section now? Do I have to do some checking in the viewAlbumsCtrl for the correct object? Since the object itself isn't named to the parameter in the URL.

Comment: You will have to loop through your albums and get the album corresponding to the name

Comment: I'd suggest using some dataService. Something like this: [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EdtA8ZYH0k4mHzqGeMvs?p=preview)

Comment: Ye I'm using a service which holds a bunch of shared properties. I got it working with the loop :) Thanks a lot for the help!